# how to add jar creation to J2EE web project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I am a newbie with maven, I created a dynamic web project in eclipse and then converted into maven project.

Instead of deploying the project in a standard container I would use embedded jetty.
How can I create in maven the appropriate jar executable with all dependencies included?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by myself at

http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2013/10/09/embedded-jetty-executable-maven.html

Basically we can add as many maven plugin as we want, adding dependencies and then packaging all togheter.